# How to structure data in Firebase for filtering potentially large datasets?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node in my realtime database with thousands of children, and want to filter on these, both quick and bandwidth saving (the latter is maybe not that important at this point, but might be when my data grows).

What is the best way of structuring this to avoid fetching all the items and doing the filtering on the client?

Here is what i'm planning on implementing, but as I have no experience with Firebase or other NoSQL databases, I do need some input :)

```
{
  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "name" : "Item 1",
      "filters": {
        "filter1" : true,
        "filter2" : true,
        "filter3" : true
      }
    },
    "item2" : {
      "name" : "Item 2",
      "filters": null
    },
    "item3" : {
      "name" : "Item 3",
      "filters": {
        "filter2" : true
      }
    },
    "item4" : {
      "name" : "Item 4",
      "filters": {
        "filter2" : true,
        "filter3" : true
      }
    },
    "item5" : {
      "name" : "Item 5",
      "filters": {
        "filter3" : true
      }
    }
    // Thousands of items
  },

  "items_by_filter1" : {
    "item1" : true
  },
  "items_by_filter2" : {
    "item1" : true,
    "item3" : true
  },
  "items_by_filter3" : {
    "item1" : true,
    "item4" : true,
    "item5" : true
  }
}
```

Am I overthinking this, or is this a good approach? What if I want to filter on several filters, should I follow the same approach and add something like this for all filter combinations (probably a struggle to maintain)?

```
"items_by_filter2_and_filter3" : {
    "item1" : true,
    "item4" : true
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you would need to add filters in the item's node too? wouldn't the *items_by_filter* do the job? I am just saying it might be a waste of database if you are not planning on displaying those filters as **tag**'s to the item..

Comment: Yes, that was the plan. To be able to visualize the filters somehow.

Comment: Then i wouldn't change a thing in here..